# Visual Basic use of EntireRow.Copy starting from a specific column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would like to copy entire rows from mutliple sheets to a target sheet.
But I would like to start the row copy from column B of the target sheet.
I tried

```
Sheet1.Range("13:32").EntireRow.Copy Sheet5.Range("2:21")
```

that works fine but starts from column A of target sheet, sheet5 ;
I then tried

```
Sheet1.Range("13:32").EntireRow.Copy Sheet5.Range("B2:21")
```

but gives an error.
Can you please help?

Thanks a lot,
Electra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`EntireRow` will always return ... well ... the entire row!
Therefore you receive an error on the second row - as there are too many cells to be inserted.

You have to resize the range using this function - it will reduce the range by one column and then offsets it to start at the second column.

```vb
Public Function resizeRowToStartFromColumnB(rg As Range) As Range

Dim rgResized As Range

With rg
    Set rgResized = .Resize(, .Columns.Count - 1).Offset(, 1)
End With

Set resizeRowToStartFromColumnB = rgResized
    
End Function
```

Within your code you could use it like:

```
resizeRowToStartFromColumnB(Sheet1.Range("13:32")).Copy Sheet5.Range("B2")
```

Comment: it doesnt work , it starts the copy in the  target sheet from column A :-/

Comment: Ok - you want to start at B2? I adjusted the code. As target for the copy action you have to specify the top left cell only